# VS Code and Chrome Debugger - How to debug Ionic App on Android Device?

Tags: android, debugging, visual-studio-code, ionic2

How do I debug an Ionic app on an Android device using VS Code and Chrome Debugger?

Chrome Debugger (vscode-chrome-debug) [documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) mentions that remote debugging can be done so I'm assuming that this means it can be done on an Android Device.

Can anyone give the steps and `launch.json` file for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi this one bothered me too for a period of time.
I use a simple approach to achieve this.

Run the command

```
cordova run android -debug
```

And I keep the android studio open along with it.

Now when your application is running on your device or simulator you can select that in Android studio and  select the process you want to debug.

**in android monitor you can get all the logs for that application.**

**Note**:- It doesn't matter what application is open in Android Studio, as long your ionic app is in debug mode you can get logs there.

Comment: Thanks Dpkstr! Appreciate your help.